# android support unicode?

Tags: android

will android OS support unicode ?

Answer (score 2):

In general yes. The phones don't ship with fonts for all the Unicode characters however. Can you be more specific about what you want.

Comment: Just to add it here, there are apps on the market that allow you to get virtual keyboards to type in other languages and alphabets. Also, you can make strings in your Java code with unicode characters through the use of "\uXXXX" where XXXX is the character code.

Answer (score 2):

Android fully supports the Unicode standard, as it is also required by Java itself (Strings are Unicode). However just because Android supports unicode fully it doesn't mean you can view every language in the world, just like a normal computer. You must have the fonts installed on the phone or set in the application to be able to see the language you want.